# How to send messages from java via viber/whatsapp

Tags: java, spring, whatsapp, viber

Are there any ways or frameworks to send message via viber/whatsapp from my accounts using java? Are they unpaid? And can i save content that is sent to me in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WhatsApp provides API using which you can send messages. You can check [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-whatsapp-messages-java-applications-twilio-api) for an example. You can check [this](https://whatsmate.github.io/2016-02-17-send-whatsapp-message-java/) as another example.